# SharePoint online app build time

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app

I have created a SharePoint App(SharePoint Add-in) with 70 columns 6 content types and 8 lists and I am deploying the Sharepoint app to SharePoint online. It takes around 16-18 mins to retract, uninstall and install and upload the application.

**Steps done so far**

- Click right solution retract solution, followed by "clean solution",followed by "build and deploy the solution".
- Incremented the app version in the app manifest.xml

Is there any step I am missing so that the app can be built and deployed in lesser time.

Can anyone suggest best practices to "build and deploy" a SharePoint app(SharePoint Add-in) to Sharepoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is notoriously slow with API calls, 300 milliseconds is not uncommon

A **very** rough calculation

( 70 * 6 * 8 * .300 ) / 60

equals to your 16 - 18 minutes

#### Do Batch updates

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34024.bulk-update-in-sharepoint-list-using-jsom.aspx
- https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Batching
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patrickrodgers/2016/06/28/pnp-jscore-1-0-2/